# Magento how to prevent data changes in observer

Tags: magento

I need to prevent some customers to change their addresses.
I found system event 'customer_address_save_(before|after)'.
Is it possible to cancel writing to database from own observer (based on some customer's conditions)? Or can I do it by rewriting system customer classes (i.e. beforeSave method)?
In short the question is how to prevent data changes in own module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try in your observer (event - customer_address_save_before) :

```
/** @var $customerAddress Mage_Customer_Model_Address */
$customerAddress = $observer->getCustomerAddress();

$origData = $customerAddress->getOrigData();
$newData = $customerAddress->getData();
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Eugene, thanks for the answer (spasibo). I checked code under customer_address_save_before event - orig_data is undefined here :(  But I found solution:     /**
     * Flag which can stop data saving after before save
     * Can be used for next sequence: we check data in _beforeSave, if data are
     * not valid - we can set this flag to false value and save process will be stopped
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_dataSaveAllowed = true;